# Run gulp with an arbitrary gulpfile name (not gulpfile.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, gulp, command-line-interface

I have one specific task in my gulpfile that is isolated from the other tasks and never needs to run as part of the rest of the build process. I'd like to put it in a separate gulpfile and execute that on its own.

How can I use `gulp` with a gulpfile that has a custom name?

The [Getting started document](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs/getting-started) posing as Gulp's docs don't seem to mention the CLI. My search attempts for arguments to the `gulp`, mostly brings up results on how to get the command line arguments into the `gulp` tasks.

The actual use case is extracting translatable strings in a Docker container, which I don't want to bloat with unnecessary node.js packages.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is what the [gulp CLI docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/CLI.md) say:

> `--gulpfile <gulpfile path>` will manually set path of gulpfile. Useful if you have multiple gulpfiles. This will set the CWD to the gulpfile directory as well

Comment: The reason the CLI docs are hard to find, is that the link to that document is hidden (in plain sight) in the file [docs/README.md](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/README.md), *above* the Recipes heading which is linked from the Getting started document.